# Cannot use variable in FFmpeg command as I wanted

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, powershell, shell, script

I am trying to do a basic hardsub work with FFmpeg in a Powershell script. Here is the code:

```
$subfile = ".\test\sub.srt"

ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v h264 -vf "subtitles=${subfile}:'force_style=fontsize=20'" out.mp4
```

When I run this, I got following error in FFmpeg:

```
"Unable to open .testsub.srt"
```

Strangely FFmpeg cut the backlashes from `$subfile` variable.

If I change the command like below (remove curly braces for `$subfile` variable):

```
$subfile = ".\test\sub.srt"

ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v h264 -vf "subtitles=$subfile:'force_style=fontsize=20'" out.mp4
```

This time PowerShell gets me an error like this:

```
"Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name."
```

In FFmpeg command above all of the `"` `'` and `:` symbols are necessary, so I can't change that unfortunetly. What should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try `$($subfile):` io `${subfile}:`

Comment: No that didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Replace with forward slashes and check.

Comment: Okay forward slashes did work! But why we use ```/```? Isn't it Linux like?

Answer (score 1):

When I tried "Gyan's" solution it worked. I also tried changing all patterns from `\` to `/` like this:

```
$subfile = ".\test\sub.srt"

$pattern = "[\\]"

$subfile = $subfile -replace $pattern, "/"

ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v h264 -vf "subtitles=${subfile}:'force_style=fontsize=20'" out.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I work on subtitles:

```
ffmpeg -y -i Bach720.mp4 -i bach.srt -vf "subtitles=bach.srt:force_style=FontName='Lobster Two,PrimaryColour=&H000000FF,FontSize=30'" BachSRT.mp4
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).